# OGV Video - Wrong Duration with video.js and WebKit Browsers

Tags: webkit, video.js

There's a strange problem with the videos I'm uploading for reproduction with video.js and WebKit browsers in general. I've tried on the very latest versions of Chrome for Windows 7 and Safari for Mac.

Here are the videos:

http://www.csdalbenga.it/videos/SonnyInterview.html

http://www.csdalbenga.it/videos/recita2012.html

They work fine, but their duration is listed as double the actual playing time. This doesn't happen with other browsers. If you forward beyond 50% of the bar, the videos go blank or restart depending on the browser.

It's not a server problem (because this also happens locally) and it's not an encoder problem. It doesn't happen if I use the default HTML5 player instead of video.js.

Can anybody lend me a hand? Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar question here and am still curious about the fix: http://superuser.com/questions/728687/why-does-ffmpeg-segment-times-create-webm-files-with-incorrect-duration-and-star

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine your mp4 file in a tool such as [mediainfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) you'll see it's metadata reports its length as 14mn 25s. Try re-exporting/re-converting it. As Chrome and Safari can play mp4 they will be playing this source.

```
Duration                                 : 14mn 25s
```

Other browsers wouldn't be affected, as they'd use one of the other formats. The webm and ogv videos' metadata is correct:

```
Duration                                 : 7mn 12s
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I thought Chrome and Safari would go for the ogv if present?

Comment: They'll play the first listed source they are capable of playing.

Comment: And thanks again. I guess mp4 has been added recently to the supported formats, an old version of Safari plays the ogv, the newest version plays the mp4.